# Подключение к базе java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте. 
Установил приложение на хостинг, создал базу, добавил таблицы, вьюхи и т.д
Выскакивает такая ошибка

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3
>   times. Giving up.

Проблема может быть в том, что я в каждом методе подключаюсь к базе ?
Но я создаю подключение в `try(Connection con = Connector.getConnection)`
А это значит, что оно постоянно открывается и закрывается.
Так в чем можем быть причина ?

Класс Connector

```
public static Connection getConnection()
        throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://zrn.mysql.ukraine.com.ua/база?" +
                    "autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false",
            "юзер",
            "пароль");
}
```

Пример подключения

```
public boolean exist(String query) throws SQLException {

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next()) return rs.getBoolean(1);
    throw new SQLException("sql exception in exist method");

}
```

Comment: Добавьте [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/move) вашего кода.

Comment: Добавил взгляните, возможно с хостингом что то не то ?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте порт `3306` - скорее всего он закрыт у вашего хостера.

Или попросите открыть этот порт для вас или укажите в коннекте другой порт.

Comment: Какие то запросы делаются, но не все. И это очень странно.